# vlookup same value between certain values in another column

Tags: google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

So I want to vlookup a certain value (search key) that repeats in that column, but each of that same value (breakfast, lunch, dinner) fall under a different category from a different column (Guests, Orders, Sales, etc.). I'll put up a sample below to help explain what I want. Thank you for any and all help :) [Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DRscb_CodUD2LeGE0Q0DSkSFuKHq5B3ICpLbuYbCo8g/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=FILTER(C:C, REGEXMATCH(A:A, "Breakfast|Lunch|Total"))
```

Comment: A `FILTER` property I was not aware of. Thank you.